# How do I debug cucumber tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, cucumber

I have:

```
When /^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/ do |link, selector|  
  with_scope(selector) do
   click_link(link)
  end
end
```

Which I call from:

```
Background:
  Given I am an existing admin user
  When I follow "CLIENTS"
```

my HTML is like this:

```
<a class="active" href="/companies"><h2>CLIENTS</h2></a>
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
.F-.F--U-----U

(::) failed steps (::)

no link with title, id or text 'CLIENTS' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
(eval):2:in `click_link'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:53:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/client_add.feature:8:in `When I follow "CLIENTS"'
```

I tried a few things from:

```
When I follow "<h2>CLIENTS</h2>"
```

and even tried the `save_and_open_page` which should open the browser and still get the same results:

```
Given /^I am an existing admin user$/ do
  role_user = FactoryGirl.create(:role_user)
  admin_user = role_user.user
  sign_in(admin_user)
  save_and_open_page
end
```

Is there a way to print the HTML or some way to figure out why my test is failing?

Comment: use capybara's save_and_open_page as given on on http://berk.es/2013/01/08/make-cucumber-open-the-browser-with-the-current-page/

Comment: also use pry_remote (https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/pry-remote) to debug in a feature test. might need to put a sleep so that timeout does not happen in the spec

Answer (score 10):

My favorite way of debugging cucumber steps is throw in a call to `binding.pry`.

Make sure the `pry` gem is included in your gem file for `:development, test` and then place the `binding.pry` call right before the line that throws the error. You should then be able to introspect the environment with the `ls` command and if you can find the capybara session running you can to (if capybara session is stored as a variable named page) `page.html` and `page.text` to see what is visible.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following as the contents of features/support/debugging.rb can be helpful in debugging failing steps:

```
# `LAUNCHY=1 cucumber` to open page on failure
After do |scenario|
  save_and_open_page if scenario.failed? && ENV['LAUNCHY']
end

# `FAST=1 cucumber` to stop on first failure
After do |scenario|
  Cucumber.wants_to_quit = ENV['FAST'] && scenario.failed?
end

# `DEBUG=1 cucumber` to drop into debugger on failure
After do |scenario|
  next unless ENV['DEBUG'] && scenario.failed?
  puts "Debugging scenario: #{scenario.title}"
  if respond_to? :debugger
    debugger
  elsif binding.respond_to? :pry
    binding.pry
  else
    puts "Can't find debugger or pry to debug"
  end 
end

# `STEP=1 cucumber` to pause after each step
AfterStep do |scenario|
  next unless ENV['STEP']
  unless defined?(@counter)
    puts "Stepping through #{scenario.title}"
    @counter = 0
  end
  @counter += 1
  print "At step ##{@counter} of #{scenario.steps.count}. Press Return to"\
        ' execute...'
  STDIN.getc
end
```

By setting an environment variable, you can cause Cucumber to use various debugging tools, and you can combine them by setting multiple environment variables.

Comment: This works great, thanks. You can set the Environment variables directly on the command line. For example
'bin/cucumber features/mytest.feature LAUNCHY=1'

or to set them for the whole terminal session with 
'export LAUNCHY=1'

Answer (score 0):

Your test is failing because you have to navigate to a page (open it). You can use capybara's built in method to do it:

```
visit path_to(url)
```

Also you can debug using standard ruby debugger. See guide [this rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-ruby-debug) to get more information.

Answer (score 0):

for my experience:

- Firstly: you should use "save_and_open_page" method in capybara to check what is on that page and consider and look it render to right page which you expect or not. (I think the page has "CLIENTS" link does not display yet)
- Second: You change the route path that redirect to page has "CLIENTS" link

hope it helps you.

p/s: if you follow my instruction but it does not work. Pls give me your feature and step definition. I will try to help you what I can